# Unrecognized expression when appending data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I try to create a HTML element with a class and data attribute via jQuery:

```
elem.append($('<ul>', {'class': 'list-group-item', 'data-topic': value}));
```

This works fine, except when the data attribute contains spaces. Then the console throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ul[data-topic=Test 2]
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use? It works for me in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyxc3goh/) with jQuery 1.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just setting it as a string? Is it perhaps because you're not getting the quotations surrounding the data attribute?

```
elem.append($('<ul class="list-group-item" data-topic="'+value+'"></ul>'));
```

Untested. Just a thought.

Comment: Nope, same error here
`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <ul class="list-group-item" data-topic="Test 2">`

Comment: Hmm, as Regent said, these two approaches should work, and do in a fiddle. I suspect it's something else causing the issue, maybe you could post the full code in a fiddle/pen?

Comment: Okay, sorry, I got the solution. You were right, I just pointed to the wrong code lines.

`settings.wrapper.find('ul[data-topic="' + value.topic + '"]').append(question);`

The double quotes were missing so I added them. Now it works fine. Thanks!